# Cycling through a list of URLs on the Grand Comic Book database

Tags: python, browser

I've recently been trying to do the following by hand, and I'm wondering if there is a quick way to automate it. My only experience is playing around with python/python3 in the terminal on Ubuntu, which is why I'm hoping to do it in python, and not some other.

Some background: The website my.comics.org is a database for comic books, where a given issue has a URL of the form `https://my.comics.org/issue/#` where `#` is some number. If one is logged into an account, there is an "Add" button that adds the issue to a chosen list. I'm trying to piece together a script that would cycle through the URLs corresponding to a numerical range and add each issue to a chosen list. The list of choice is saved in the browser so doesn't need to be specified, so it is sufficient to just click the button. Inspecting the "Add" button, there is the following line in the html

```
<input type="submit" name="confirm_selection" value="Add">`
```

which I hope is enough info to tell the script which button to click.

I know I can open webpages with the webbrowser module, but I don't know how to open a URL, click the "Add" button, close the tab, and then repeat over a given range.

Just experimenting, I tried something like this in python the command line

```
import webbrowser
for i in range(1,5):
    webbrowser.open('https://my.comics.org/issue/'+str(i))
```

This opened a bunch of tabs, but I got several errors like

```
Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
```

I also don't want to open all tabs simultaneously as I'd like to run the script over a range of, say, 1000 issues. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had some free time, so I made an account on my.comics.org.

I wouldn't use the `webbrowser` module for this. Instead, I would use the `requests` module. Using `requests`, you can make HTTP GET and POST requests (and some others as well) to websites. The idea is that you create a request payload and submit it to the desired URL, so that you can more-or-less mimic the "actions" you would perform in a browser. The hardest part is making your requests well-formed, and knowing what to put in them so that the receiving server will accept them.

Here is the code I came up with (Note, I'm using f-strings in several places, which is a Python 3.6 feature. If you don't have f-strings you can just do plain old string formatting):

```
def main():
    import requests

    login_url = "https://my.comics.org/accounts/login/"

    client = requests.session()

    # First, get the CSRF token.
    client.get(login_url)
    csrf_token = client.cookies["csrftoken"]


    email = "YOUR EMAIL GOES HERE"
    password = "YOUR PASSWORD GOES HERE"

    credentials = {
        "username": email,
        "password": password,
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token,
        "next": "/"
        }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": login_url,
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Host": "my.comics.org",
        "Origin": "https://my.comics.org"
        }

    request = client.post(login_url, data=credentials, headers=headers)

    # We should be logged in now.
    # Here is where we can start adding the issues to our desired collection(s).

    issue_numbers = [41485, 41486, 41487]
    collection_id = "27402"

    number_of_issues = len(issue_numbers)

    for issue_index, issue_number in enumerate(issue_numbers):
        issue_url = f"https://my.comics.org/issue/{issue_number}/add_to_collection/"

        # Get the CSRF token again.
        client.get(issue_url)
        csrf_token = client.cookies["csrftoken"]

        data = {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token,
            "confirm_selection": "Add",
            "collection_id": collection_id,
            }

        headers["Referer"] = issue_url

        print(f"({issue_index+1}/{number_of_issues}) Adding issue# {issue_number} to collection# {collection_id}...")
        request = client.post(issue_url, data=data, headers=headers)

    print("All done!")

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Some notes:

The first step is to create a requests session, much like how your browser creates a session for you when you visit a website. The next thing we'd like to do is to log into our account. To do that, we need a "username" (email) and password. We also need this thing called a CSRF token, which is a one-time-use cookie that the server sends to you to uniquely identify your session. The way we set this up is by creating a dictionary which maps "username" to your email, "password" to your password etc. We're almost ready to submit our first POST request, but you'll also have to provide a header to the server, which kind of describes your client and where you're coming from (servers typically want to see this as well to ensure your request is authentic).

After our first POST request, we should be logged in now (note, unlike with the webbrowser module, none of this will open any tabs or browser instances. It's all happening behind the scenes). Once we're logged in we can iterate over the issues we're interested in adding to our collection(s).

NOTICE, for my collection_id, I picked the value "27402". You'll probably have to change this value, because this is the ID of my collection (I made a "python collection" just for this project). The way I figured out the ID of the collection I want to add to, is by looking at the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/issue/41485/add_to_collection/">
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='REDACTED, NORMALLY A BUNCH OF RANDOM CHARACTERS' />
  <div>

    <input type="submit" name="confirm_selection" value="Add">
    this issue to your 
    <select name="collection_id">

      <option value="27400" >Default have collection

      <option value="27401" >Default want collection

      <option value="27402" >python collection

    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Notice, the "value" of my python collection. That's the ID of the collection that we can select from the drop down window under the "Add" button.

The way we add the individual issue numbers to our collection, is by iterating/looping over our list of issue numbers (in this case I just picked three random ones). For every issue number in the list, we need to get a new CSRF token, and change the "Referer" field in our header dictionary (to reflect the new place we're coming from). Then, the POST request in the loop is the one that actually adds the current issue to the specified collection.

And, just in case you're curious, here is the output I get in the terminal:

```
(1/3) Adding issue# 41485 to collection# 27402...
(2/3) Adding issue# 41486 to collection# 27402...
(3/3) Adding issue# 41487 to collection# 27402...
All done!
```

And, my comic collection after logging into my account in the browser:
[image: My "Python collection" after running the script]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I wouldn't have known how to to do this. I appreciate the notes explaining a little about what is happening. That's helpful for someone like me who is interested in learning what's going on, but who is quite out of her element.

Comment: Absolutely. Let me know if you have any questions.